# xargs cat with conditional statement

Tags: unix, cat, xargs

I am dealing with the unix xargs cat, i am not really into unix and at the moment i have a cat command like this:

```
    ls *ex_vs*ex.txt | xargs cat > ex.txt

    ls *en_vs*en.txt | xargs cat > en.txt
```

What i want to do now is make a statement that has this meaning:

```
    ls *ex_vs*en.txt **OR** *en_vs*ex.txt | xargs cat > en_ex.txt
```

so my question is basically how to put a conditional statement (or) for catting files together.
Any suggestion will be very much appreciated.
Best
Alfredo

Comment: it's not clear why you think you need `xargs`. Generally, you can just use `cat *en_vs*en.txt > en.txt`. AND your requirement for **OR** is also unclear. Why not just do `cat *en.txt > en_all.txt ; cat *ex.txt > ex_all.txt ; cat > en_all.txt  ex_all.txt > all.txt`. If there are no files matching either `*ex.txt` or `*en.txt` it will be a no-op, and processing will continue. the final file will have the correct result. Good luck.

Comment: thanks, you are right, works also like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ls** can take multiples arguments :

```
$ ls --help
Usage: ls [OPTION]... [FILE]...
```

So you can add both file selectors after the ls :

```
ls *ex_vs*en.txt *en_vs*ex.txt | xargs cat > en_ex.txt
```

You can also use :

```
 cat *ex_vs*en.txt *en_vs*ex.txt > en_ex.txt
```